# Select values from a table that are not in a list SQL

Tags: sql

If I type:

```
SELECT name FROM table WHERE name NOT IN ('Test1','Test2','Test3');
```

I can get the entries from the table that are not in the list. I want to do the opposite: Get the values from the list that are not in the table. For example, if table has a column named name that has the values 'Test1' and 'Test3' I want to compare that to ('Test1','Test2','Test3') and return Test2. Or as another example, if the table is empty, then return everything in the list: Test1, Test2, and Test3.

Is there a way to do this WITHOUT creating a new table with all of the values in the list?

Comment: What database are you using (oracle? sql server?)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Depending on how many values you have, you could do a few unions.

See: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!5/0e42f/1

```
select * from (
  select 'Test 1' thename union
  select 'Test 2' union 
  select 'Test 3'
)
where thename not in (select name from foo)
```

Comment: I discovered it yesterday. It's pretty slick.

Comment: I got `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'` - had to give the table a name, e.g. `select * from (...) t where ...`.

Answer (score 2):

I usually use `SELECT 'FOO' AS COL UNION SELECT 'BAR'` etc and then use the standard idiom of left joining and checking for `NULL` to find missing elements.

```
CREATE TABLE #YourTable(
name nvarchar(50)
)

insert into #YourTable (name) values ('Test1'), ('Test3')

-- ALL
select * from #YourTable

--MISSING
select t1.* from (
  select 'Test1' testName
  union select 'Test2'
  union select 'Test3') as t1
  left outer join #YourTable yt on t1.testName = yt.name
  where yt.name is null

DROP TABLE #YourTable
```

Gives output

```
name
--------------------------------------------------
Test1
Test3

(2 row(s) affected)

testName
--------
Test2

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select a.value from (
SELECT 'testvalue' value UNION
SELECT 'testvalue2' value UNION
SELECT 'testvalue3' value UNION
SELECT 'testvalue4' value UNION
) a
left outer join othertable b
on a.value=b.value
where b.value is null
```

This is perfect for my problem without temp table#

Answer (score 0):

Assuming "othertable" holds the table in question...

```
 select a.value from 
    (select 'test1' value
     union
     select 'test2' value
     union 
     select 'test3' value) a
       left outer join othertable b
         on a.value=b.value
      where b.value is null
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL server, the below query works well.

```
SELECT v.val FROM (VALUES 
    ('A'), 
    ('B'), 
    ('C'), 
    ('D'), 
    ('E') 
) v (val)
LEFT JOIN dbo.TABLE_NAME t ON t.COLUMN_NAME = v.val
WHERE t.COLUMN_NAME IS NULL;
```

Can find the below output:

```
val
-------
A
B
C
D
```